# How to prevent html2canvas to take screenshots after show my pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, jspdf-autotable

I'm using jspdf autotable and html2canvas in React.js to create and show a pdf on my page. Everything works well but after My pdf is showen on teh pop-Up then an extra screenshot is added at below on my page. I want to prevent this screenshot.

When you look at the first picture , everything works well and I can see my pdf on the pop-up. But When I close that pop-up then a screenshot is created at below. You can see it at second picture. Is there any way to prevent it?
[image: Picture1]
[image: Picutre2]

Here is my code:

```
doc.autoTable({
        showHead:'firstPage',
        margin:5,
        startY: 60,
        body: bodyData,
        columns: [
          { header: 'Sıra', dataKey: 'Count' },
          { header: 'Gelir Tipi', dataKey: 'AccrumentTypeName' },
          { header: 'Gelir Türü', dataKey: 'RevenueName' },
          { header: 'Tahakkuk Tutarı', dataKey: 'TotalAmount' },
        ],
        styles: {
            font: 'NotoSans-Regular',
            lineWidth: 0.2,
            lineColor: 0,
            fontSize:7,
          },
        didParseCell: function (data) {
            var rows = data.table.body;
            if (data.row.index === rows.length - 1) {
                data.cell.styles.fillColor = [176, 224, 230];
            }
        }
    })

const pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    doc.setFontSize(8)
    for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        doc.setPage(i)
        doc.text('Sayfa ' + String(i) + ' / ' + String(pageCount), doc.internal.pageSize.width / 2, 294, {
            align: 'center'
        })
    }

    //Create screenshot of body
    html2canvas(document.body, {scale: 2,scrollY: 0,height: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight, windowHeight: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight, }).then(canvas => {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       let output = doc.output('bloburl');
       document.getElementById("pdfObj").height = canvas.height / 4;
       document.getElementById("pdfObj").data = output;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. The problem is that html2canvas is creating  as a screenshot in index.html every time I call it. Therefore I set

```
<style>
  canvas{
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

in index.html. Then it works!